# VBNET display specific query using form input

Tags: vb.net

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a form where I need to fill it out with a specific number.
When this happens, I want to inject that input into my query command.

It will then show the query results (possibly in a table).

I'm fairly new to vbnet (and coding in general).
I was able to get my code to work with classic ASP but I don't know the correct lingo for vbnet.

Based off one of the searches I've found earlier, this is what I have so far. Probably doesn't make sense but I'm trying to do the best I can.

```
Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(serverinfo)
Dim myTable As New DataTable()
Dim myCmd As New SqlCommand()
myCmd.Connection = myConn
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x="+ x.Text+ " AND y="+ y.Text+ " AND z="+ z.Text+ " AND w="+ w.Text

Dim myAdapater As New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd)
myAdapter.Fill(myTable)

DataGridView2.DataSource = myTable
results.InnerHTML=displayoutput
```

-all variables are supposed to be As integers.
-displayoutput is supposed to be the column headers portion.
Am I grabbing them from the form correctly using the id attribute?

Comment: Don't use form input value directly. It will cause SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will access the database and populate the `GridView` for you.

```
using conn as new sqlconnection("connstring"), comm as new sqlcommand("",conn)
    conn.open
    comm.commandtype = commandtype.text
    comm.commandtext = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x=@x AND y=@y AND z=@x AND w=@w"

    comm.parameters.addwithvalue("@w",w.text)
    comm.parameters.addwithvalue("@x",x.text)
    comm.parameters.addwithvalue("@y",y.text)
    comm.parameters.addwithvalue("@z",z.text)

    Dim dt as new datatable
    dim sa as new sqldataadapter()
    sa.selectcommand = comm
    sa.fill(ds)

    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView2.databind
end using
```

On your `GridView` set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true` and the columns that you've selected will appear.

If you're using `Winforms`, you may not need the databind bit, I can't remember.

Comment: so after creating the sub Page_Load and closing it, i would make another sub say... 

    `sub findacct(byval sender as object, byval e as event.args)`

do I put code you supplied here?
    `end sub`


basically the bottom of my page is the html with forms...something along the lines of 
    `<asp:TextBox id="x" MaxLength="4" columns="4" Runat="server">    </asp:TextBox>
<br>
    <asp:Button id="btnAdd" onclick="FindAcct" Runat="server" Text="Find Account"></asp:Button></asp:panel>`

is the forms part even correct or did i misplace the code?

thanks for the help!